# Merging branch into master in Xcode 11?

Tags: xcode, git, merge, branch

I must be missing something very simple here. I never had a problem merging branches into master on earlier versions of Xcode, but I don't have the option on any projects while using Xcode 11.

[image: branch right-click]
[image: master right-click]

How should I merge into master? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a frustrating Xcode 11 issue. 
As a workaround you can checkout `master` first and then merge the required branch into it.

Comment: Confirming that this works. Couldn't find a solution anywhere else. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am using Xcode Version 11.3.1 and this is still an issue in Xcode.

Comment: Still an issue in 12.2.

Comment: I didn't need to checkout master. Just right clicking on master (from the source control navigator) and then selecting: `merge 'master' into <my-current-branch>`

Comment: @Honey, the question is about doing the opposite. Merging `<my-current-branch>` that is checked out now into a `master`.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize that